# Append elements to different lists based on if-else statements in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have been trying to create the following program in Python. However, I am getting frustrated with my program, and I have no idea what I should be doing! Specifically, I am having trouble appending elements to different lists based on my if-else statements. What is supposed to happen is the userInputMembers should get assigned to an array depending on the number of new members inputted by the user, so the program outputs how many new members are assigned to each array.

Instead, I just end up with empty arrays. I am still learning how Python works, so right now I am just really confused!

Here is what the final output of my program looks like:

```
Number of Trainers: []
0 trainers have 0-5 new enrollees
0 trainers have 6-10 new enrollees
0 trainers have 11-15 new enrollees
```

Below is the code for my current program:

```py
   #Declare variables:
   NUM_MEMBERS = 15
   trainerNames = []
   newMembers = []
   newMembers1 = []
   newMembers2 = []
   newMembers3 = []

  #Intitialize loop:
   for i in range(NUM_MEMBERS):
    userInputTrainers = input("Enter a trainer's last name")
    userInputMembers = input("Enter the number of new members enrolled")

for userInputMembers in newMembers:
    a = userInputMembers[1]
    if a <= 5:
          newMembers1.append(userInputMembers)

    elif 5 < a <= 10:
        newMembers2.append(userInputMembers)

    elif 10 < a <= 15:
        newMembers3.append(userInputMembers)

    else:
        print("Sorry, there isn't a category for that.") 
 
    userInputTrainers = trainerNames
    trainerNames = len(trainerNames)

    print("Number of Trainers:",trainerNames)
    print(len(newMembers1), "trainers have 0-5 new enrollees.")
    print(len(newMembers2), "trainers have 6-10 new enrollees")
    print(len(newMembers3), "trainers have 11-15 new enrollees")
```

*edit: I realize that my post is a duplicate of other people's post who have attempted the same assignment in python. I found someone else's code that was "fixed" (included below)

- Apologies to the person's original post whom I took the following code from. I have attempted to recognize who they are, but I lost their post in the process.

Here is an answer I have found to my problem above from another post:

```py
#Declare variables:
newMembers1 = []
newMembers2 = []
newMembers3 = []


newMembers = []
for i in range(1, 15):
    t = input(f"Enter Trainer {i} Name: ")
    n = int(input(f"Enter Trainer {i} # of enrollees: "))
    L = [t, n]
    newMembers.append(L)
```

I realize that their code works better than mine because of how they assigned each input to a different variable, and appended it to data.append as shown above. Based on their code, I have attempted to fix my code as shown below:

```py
#Declare variables:
newMembers1 = []
newMembers2 = []
newMembers3 = []


newMembers = []
for i in range(1, 15):
    t = input(f"Enter Trainer {i} Name: ")
    n = int(input(f"Enter Trainer {i} # of enrollees: "))
    L = [t, n]
    newMembers.append(L)

for trainers in newMembers:
    a = trainers[1]
    if a <= 5:
      if type(n) == int:
          newMembers1.append(trainers)

    elif 5 < a <= 10:
      if type(n) == int:
        newMembers2.append(trainers)

    elif 10 < a <= 15:
      if type(n) == int:
        newMembers3.append(trainers)

    else:
         print("Sorry, there isn't a category for that.") 

print(len(newMembers1), "trainers have 0-5 new enrollees.")
print(len(newMembers2), "trainers have 6-10 new enrollees")
print(len(newMembers3), "trainers have 11-15 new enrollees")
```

Comment: `if userInputMembers == category0_5` doesn't work, that will compare a single string with a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) object. You need `if int(userInputMembers) in category0_5`.

Comment: Oh and not to mention that `category0_5 == range(0,5)` is *comparison* not assignment. Please actually *try* running your code, as that would have lead to an error.

Comment: Or maybe that error is what you're asking about? Please take some time to read [ask], as well as about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You talk about "arrays" in your question, but there is no [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) in your code. What you have is a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots wrong here.

First, you never actually add anything to `newMembers`.  It starts out as an empty list, and it stays that way.  How were you expecting anything to get added to it?

Second, these three lines don't actually do anything, because you're using `==` which is a *comparison*, not an *assignment*:

```
    category0_5 == range(0,5)
    category6_10 == range(6,10)
    category11_15 == range(11,15)
```

Third, this comparison will never be true, because `input()` returns a string.  You need to convert the input to an integer.

```
if userInputMembers == category0_5:
```

And even if you did convert to an integer, it still wouldn't be true, because an integer is not *equal* to a range.  Did you mean to check if the range *contains* the integer?  Use `in` instead of `==`:

```
if userInputMembers in category0_5:
```

And even then, it *still* might not be true, because `range()` does **not** include the final number.  So `range(0,5)` includes 0,1,2,3,4. It does **not** include 5.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help! I realize that range may not be the best command, I should probably have used comparisons like if userInputMembers <= 5, or something like that. I found someone else's post with the same problem that I have, and I am trying to look at their code. Unfortunately, I think I lost their post, but I will try to edit my code above using their comparisons.

Comment: @Selah You can use an expression like this `if 6 <= x <= 10:`

Comment: Great! does my code look better now?

Comment: @Selah Run it, and see if it does what you want.

Comment: It is no longer displaying any of my print statements.

Comment: Never mind, It was just a typo. (See edited code above.) However, my lists are still empty.

Comment: Here is the output from my code when I try to run it: Number of Trainers: []
0 trainers have 0-5 new enrollees
0 trainers have 6-10 new enrollees
0 trainers have 11-15 new enrollees

Comment: @Selah Your question contains two very different versions of the code, so I have no idea what code you're actually running.  And as posted, the code has obvious indentation errors, so that can't be your actual real code because it wouldn't even run.  If you want help, you must be **clear** about providing your actual real code.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. Hopefully it makes more sense now! I was trying to compare my code with someone else's code that I found from another post. I was confused because I had trouble with the "append" command. Using the other person's code, I was able to make my code work better, so I edited it appropriately. I am happy to say that it works now!

Comment: As with the indentation errors, It may have gotten messed up when I tried to copy and paste my code to the forum. It works when I run it, so I know that the original code has appropriate spacing even if the code that I posted above doesn't!

Comment: If the **posted** code isn't correct, it's a lot harder for us to help.  We can't see the code on your local pc.